# Find intersection of 2 arrays in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I have 2 arrays (batsmen and bowlers). Whats the best way to find the intersection of these and create the allrounders array?

```
public type Player record {
    int id;
    string name;
};

Player[] batsmen = [
    {id: 1, name: "Virat"},
    {id: 2, name: "Rohit"},
    {id: 3, name: "Jadeja"}
];

Player[] bowlers = [
    {id: 3, name: "Jadeja"},
    {id: 4, name: "Bumrah"},
    {id: 5, name: "Shami"}
];

Player[] allrounders = [];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import ballerina/io;
public type Player record {
    int id;
    string name;
};

Player[] batsmen = [
    {id: 1, name: "Virat"},
    {id: 2, name: "Rohit"},
    {id: 3, name: "Jadeja"}
];

Player[] bowlers = [
    {id: 3, name: "Jadeja"},
    {id: 4, name: "Bumrah"},
    {id: 5, name: "Shami"}
];

Player[] allrounders = [];
public function main() {
    allrounders = from Player batsman in batsmen join Player bowler in bowlers on batsman.id equals bowler.id
    select batsman;
    io:println(allrounders);
}
```

You can find more details on `join` in here
https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/outer-join-clause/